# I cannot set permissions to read a file in my project directory using Xcode 14 and Swift 5 on macOS Ventura

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox

I'm writing a minimal app to learn how to read a file with UInt16 data that can be displayed as an image.  It finally compiles but crashes at runtime with a file read permission error.  I've attempted to give the app permission for read and write files, the permissions appear to say that I have read and write permissions.

It crashes on the second line:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/<user>/<some path/<some file with ext .raw>")   
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
```

with this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “p03-4M1-041.raw” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/nate/2008 11 15 Freeway Fire/p03/p03-4M1-041.raw, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002d72a90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

I think that this is an Xcode problem as the Assets.xcasssets appears to be empty and there is no plist.

I'm using Xcode 14, Swift5, on my macBook running Ventura.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 File Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989098/nscocoaerrordomain-code-257-file-permission)

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @koen I added the line of code from your reference, it apparently returned true but did no good.  I now think that I need to edit the Assets.xcassets file to give the app permissions for reading my files but I don't know how.

Comment: Update your question and show how you initialize `fileURL`. You should not be trying to read anything from the project folder. You should be accessing files from the app's resource bundle. Are you building a command-line program or a full macOS app (AppKit/SwiftUI)?

Comment: @Willeke OK, I added the line that creates the URL.   Try it on your macBook but make certain that the file content has an even number of bytes. This is about as minimal as it gets.

Comment: @HangarRash This was to be a simple test of reading a USER file and displaying it as an image. The file is not a project file and not in the bundle.  The app is macOS using SwiftUI.  To be able to read the file do I need to add a file-picker or can permissions be granted somehow?  It's my second attempt to use Swift and SwiftUI.

Comment: @NateLockwood A macOS app is sandboxed. You would need to enable the "User Selected File" file access permission in the App Sandbox section. Then you would need use the standard file chooser. Then your app would have permission to access just the selected file. You can't access any arbitrary file you happen to create a file URL for.

Comment: @HangerRash OK, that's clear now.  There's a standard file chooser?  For a file that doesn't fit CSV, TXT, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macOS app is sandboxed. To access files outside of your app's resource bundle you would need to enable the "User Selected File" file access permission in the App Sandbox section of your project's target on the "Signing and Capabilities" tab.

You would then need use the standard file chooser (such as `NSOpenPanel`). Then your app would have permission to access just the selected file(s). You can't access any arbitrary file you happen to create a file URL for.

Besides enabling "User Selected File", you can also grant access to standard folders such as "Downloads" and a few others. Then your app could directly access files in the folders your app has been granted access to.